# Prove that the greatest area which the $\Delta APY$ can have is $3\sqrt3\frac{a^2}{8}$sq units

Tags: supremum-and-infimum

From a fixed point $A$ on the circumference of a circle of radius $a$,let the perpendicular $AY$ fall on the tangent at a point $P$ on the circle,prove that the greatest area which the $\Delta APY$ can have is $3\sqrt3\frac{a^2}{8}$sq units.

I cannot solve this question.How to determine the area of $\Delta APY$ which is to be maximized by differentiating.Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** place the center of the circle at the origin and the point $A$ at $(-a,0)$. An arbitrary point $P$ on the circle can be described as $(a\cos t, a\sin t)$, $t\in[0,2\pi]$. Express the area of the corresponding right angle triangle $APY$ as a function of $t$ and maximize it.

Comment: Sir,$Y$ is not on the circle.Point P is on the circle.

Comment: @VinodKumarPunia OK, sorry, just exchange $P\leftrightarrow Y$.

Comment: The area of $APY$ calculated using this method comes out to be $\frac{1}{2}a^2\cot^2\frac{t}{2}$ which does not maximize to desired value,Sir.

Comment: @VinodKumarPunia It does not look right. If you set $t=0$ you'll get $\infty$. How is it possible for the area to be so large?